# How to integrate Infusionsoft API?

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

I have created my infusiosoft account Once I login to my account  Its redirect me to the following  page

https://signin.infusionsoft.com/app/central/home.

There I am seeing  only one account (Market Place) under my accounts. I would like to add my new account there. what should i do ? Should I be a paid user to do that?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the infusionsoft support people...

Comment: Hey Keill, 
  The question has been posted to the support team via email, But no response from their side. Have you integrated this API before?

Comment: Integrate it with what? Your question doesn't have anything to do with the API...

Comment: Integrate in my website with the help of PHP

Comment: can you guide me to integration infusionsoft with java app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should buy an account or should have sandbox test account to work on Infusionsoft API. With these free account we cannot test integration